# ¿Cómo centrar un Jtable en un Jframe?

Tags: java

Saludos colegas.
Estoy haciendo una aplicación e intento poner un `jtable` dentro de un `jpanel`, pero me sale alineada hacia la izquierda. Quisiera que saliera en el centro pero no me lo permite.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/18562/edit) para agregar la parte del código relevante en cuestión.

Answer (score 1):

Un ejemplo para poder hacer eso seria esto:

```
import javax.swing.JTable; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleTable1 extends JFrame {

public SimpleTable1() { 
super("Ejemplo 1");

//Array bidimensional de objetos con los datos de la tabla 
Object[][] data = { 
{"Mary", "Campione", "Esquiar", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)}, 
{"Lhucas", "Huml", "Patinar", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)}, 
{"Kathya", "Walrath", "Escalar", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)}, 
{"Marcus", "Andrews", "Correr", new Integer(7), new Boolean(true)}, 
{"Angela", "Lalth", "Nadar", new Integer(4), new Boolean(false)} 
};

//Array de ‘String’ con los titulos de las columnas 
String[] columnNames = {"Nombre", "Apellido", "Pasatiempo", "Años de Practica", "Soltero(a)"};

//Creacion de la tabla 
final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames); 
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 80));

//Creamos un scrollpanel y se lo agregamos a la tabla 
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

//Agregamos el scrollpanel al contenedor 
getContentPane().add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//manejamos la salida 
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { 
System.exit(0); 
} 
}); 
}

public static void main(String ar[]) { 
SimpleTable1 frame = new SimpleTable1(); 
frame.pack(); 
frame.setVisible(true); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar un `GridLayout`, ya que divide el `JFrame` en múltiples casillas, si solo quieres poner el `JTable` en el centro, o usar un `GridBagLayout` si deseas recolocar múltiples elementos en cualquier posición del `JFrame`.

Esto se hace canviando el controlador de posicionamiento del contenidor, con éste método `unJFrame.getContentPane().setLayout();`.

Aquí te dejo información sobre el `GridLayout`
http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/applets/diseno/flow.htm

Y aquí del `GridBagLayout` http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/applets/diseno/gridbag.htm

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

[java](/questions/tagged/java)